# Convert List box filter to check box filter

Tags: spotfire

If the number of values in filter are more than 100 than spotfire automatically sets the filter as list box filter. 
when trying to convert to checkbox filter by right clicking and change filter type then check box filter option is disabled.
Is there any way to convert list box filter to display the values as check boxes.
I am using spotfire 7.0

Thanks

Comment: This https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-bauthor/7.6.0/doc/html/en-US/GUID-4B7FE19C-82ED-41BD-8746-8594F52C3E02.html   is what I exactly need. But I dont see the option to enable check boxes. Could some one please help me on this

Comment: Are you against using the filter in a text area?

Comment: My filter is in data panel only. Not in text area.

Comment: And i assume you don't want to add a text area, correct?

Comment: yes text area is not requierd now. I just loaded a data table and I would like to convert one of the list box filters having more than 100 values to a  check box filter. Once I achieve this then i can make use of this check box filter in my scripts.